# Javascript: what is the $result.rows.item(x) variable type?

Tags: javascript, json, web-sql

I had a function that reads displays the contents of the SELECT query coming from WEBSQL of HTML5. I want to reuse that function but I have the problem since what am I getting is an Array of JSON object and I want to convert it it rows.item() so do anyone know how that works?

Example, I have this JSON Array

```
"retdic":[{"row_index":0,"lname":"Mato","age":26,"gender":"M","pic":"cyborg.jpg","fname":"Shibiru"},
          {"row_index":1,"lname":"Taro","age":30,"gender":"M","pic":"folder_wrench.png","fname":"Ichigo"},
          {"row_index":2,"lname":"Joni","age":27,"gender":"M","pic":"naruto.jpg","fname":"Perez"},
          {"row_index":3,"lname":"Sakura","age":24,"gender":"F","pic":"folder_table.png","fname":"Haruka"},              
          {"row_index":4,"lname":"Naruto","age":20,"gender":"M","pic":"naruto.jpg","fname":"Uzumaki"}]
```

How can I convert it to like $result.rows.item()? item() is not an array right coz if it is an array it should be item[].

**UPDATE**

Using the idea and help of Jeff I figured out how to do it. See the [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/QS6Mx/)

Comment: I up-voted your question because it helps me alot which you shared jeff's idea it totally worked for me I was passing json data from ios native code to Javascript and the webPage was using result.rows.item(x) to retrive it, this did the trick thanks mate

Comment: I only have to change a little var result = Object();
    result['rows'] = Object();result['rows']['length'] = jsonResult.length;
    result['rows']['item'] = function(i) {return jsonResult[i]};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so assuming that the only difference between your array and the item() function is that one is an array and the other a function (I'm assuming that you use item() as "$result.rows.item(3)" to get the 4th row), is pretty simple.
Just define a function which takes a parameter i and returns the item at index i in the array.
So:

```
var myItemFunction = function(i) {
     return retdic[i]
}
```

Comment: hi Jeff thanks for this, this is working. but I want that function to be like $result.rows.item(). i tried var $result.rows.item = function(i){return retdic[i]} but it doesnt work. can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to convert this object, you can access your data in this way:

```
$result.retdic[0].lname // 0 - row number
```

or in a loop :

```
var i,item;
for (i in $result.retdic) {
  item = $result.retdic[i];
  console.log(item.fname)
}
```

P.S.: if you wish, you can rename the 'retdic' key to 'rows'

```
$res = {"rows":[
  {"name": "a"},
  {"name": "b"},
  {"name": "c"}
]};


var someKey = 'name',
valueOfSomeKey = $res.rows[rowNumberHere][someKey];
```

Comment: thanks but this is not exactly what im after. but thanks anyway for your time irishka